# Avoid AngularJS bar-footer to overlap content

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, footer

I'm in my way to do an app with ionic and angularJS and i'm trying to make my bar-footer not to overlap the few content that there's in the end, so the content has to finish being shown and, then, footer is the last thing there without overlapping something, which property do I have to apply? Because I've tried all about `position` property and none of them has worked for me, here I leave you an image of what's happening now:

http://s23.postimg.org/b9uhjq0ej/Captura.png

As you can see, my last item of the list is overlapped by my footer.
Thank you all for your answers and help! :)

--EDITED (providing code):

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list class="pagina">
        <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="poblacio in poblacions"  href="#/app/ambFiltreActivitats" ng-click="doGuardarPoblacio(poblacio.title)">
            <img style="width:50px; height:auto; margin-left: 60px;" ng-src="{{poblacio.url}}"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <b>{{poblacio.title}}</b>
        </a>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
  <div class="bar bar-footer">
    <div class="title"></div>
  </div>
```

And no, I have no CSS property but background-color one, If I apply `position: relative` the footer does not even show, and with `absolute` or `fixed` it remains the same as in the photo of the link.

Comment: right now you probably have `position: fixed` or `absolute`. Give it `relative`. And give `padding-bottom : 40px` to the previous div before the footer. That should fix it. Also, please provide the code you are using. That way more people can answer and provide more helpful inputs.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida alright, already edited, take a look at it if you want, as I said in the edited part, relative does not work, thanks anyway :)

Comment: can you provide the css for `.pagina` and `.bar-footer`?

Comment: @JoelAlmeida `.bar-footer` css is `background-color: #FDC47F;` and there is no more CSS, everything is stablished by Ionic Framework, it's a list inside the `<ion-content>` tag and the footer out there :)

Answer (score 0):

Add 'has-footer' to `<ion-content>` can solve this problem.